# redirect single folder to get variable

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have a website which I want to make bilingual.
for this I'd like to redirect based on a folder so e.g.: http://www.example.com/de/aboutUs.php should link to http://www.example.com/aboutUs.php?lang=de

how do I get this done by redirect rules in an htaccess file?

I found some answers online, but all for multiple folders which doesn't seem to work in this case with only a single folder.

thanks for your help.

regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-\s\.]+)?$ $2?lang=$1 [NC,L]
```